# Is it safe to use a computer during a storm?

Tags: desktop-computer, surge-protection, weather

Is it safe to use a computer during a storm that might involve lightning discharges? I'm talking about normal every day usage like browsing the web and gaming, not stuff like installing OS or BIOS updates. I'm mainly worried about permanent damage to my computer hardware, but if there are any additional risks involved, those can be relevant as well.

In case it matters, my computer is plugged into a surge protector ([this one](https://www.mediamarkt.be/nl/product/_chacon-contactdoos-grijs-49812-1158842.html)) and I live in a normal Belgian residential house with 1 upper floor and an attic.

Comment: Also check the "linked" questions (in the side/bottom bar) on the duplicate. There are quite a few related questions there.

Comment: Probably not but that would be the least of your problems. A direct hit on your house will cause major structural damage and possibly a fire. As well as this you will get huge power surges through any surviving mains wiring which will probably fry and destroy your computer.

A surge protector will protect equipment from normal power surges including that of nearby lightning but not from a direct hit.

Comment: In Belgium there are are lightning rods on top of most houses, directing lightning strikes away from the houses directly into the ground. Other lighting might hit the streets directly which may cascade back into the powergrid which could possibly hit your house. In that case, other devices might suffer too, but a surge protector will protect you from such strike, and the chances are really really small.

Comment: @troubleshooter Houses in Belgium are equipped with lightning rods, so a direct strike on a house is very unlikely.

Comment: Provided clamping voltage and joule ratings are [sufficient](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/home/surge-protector7.htm), it's unlikely electronics would be damaged, as the surge protector will either fail, preventing voltage and current passing to the outlets, or it will trip the internal breaker if equipped with one. Generally speaking, it's recommended to have PCs plugged into a UPS or a surge protector with built-in voltage monitoring and circuit breaker, such as the [Panamax Power360](https://www.panamax.com/product/power360-6-outlet-wall-tapcharging-station-P360-DOCK)